# Deactivates a InfoPath form template from the SharePoint online Modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

Microsoft will keep supporting [InfoPath till 2026](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/), Now I am working on the transformation where I wanted to remove / disassociate InfoPath form form list.

I found that there is a PowerShell script [Disable-SPInfoPathFormTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/disable-spinfopathformtemplate?view=sharepoint-server-ps), it will deactivates a InfoPath form template from the specified site collection.

But Module is "sharepoint-server" and it Applies to "SharePoint Server Subscription Edition"

I an looking for PowerShell / alternative approve For SharePoint online Modern site.

Comment: In the SharePoint modern list, it uses PowerApps not InfoPath.

Comment: It is the Migrated list from SharePoint On-Prem to SharePoint Online